# How to store video playing progress time in database in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a users table and lesson table. In users table I have watch_history column in which I want to store the data of current playing lesson_id and currentTime of video so the user can continue watching from skip or left video.

I am new to ajax so I don't know how to send the data continuously to database using ajax.

This is my JS code which is printing the currentTime in console.

```
<script> 
    var vid = document.getElementById("player"); 

    $(function() {

        var timeout;
         
        $("#player").on("playing pause", function(e) {

            // save reference
            var v = this

            // clear previous timeout, if any
            clearTimeout(timeout)

            // call immediately if paused or when started
            performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration)
            
            // set up interval to fire very 5 seconds
            if (e.type === "playing") {
              timeout = setInterval(function() {
            performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration)
              }, 3000)
            }
        })

        function performaction(currentTime, duration) {
            console.log(currentTime);
        }

    })
   
</script>
```

How can I send the timing of video with lesson id in one array using ajax in Laravel. I am using the plry.io video player. This above JS code is present on the Lesson_video.blade.php page on which I have the lesson id.

I am working on a college project.

Comment: `var data = {time: currentTime}; //data to send to server
var dataType = "json"//expected datatype from server
$.post({
  url: '/saveTime/'+videoId+'/'+userId,//url of the server which stores time data
  data: data,
  success: function(data,status){alert(status);alert(JSON.parse(data));},
  dataType: dataType
});`

Comment: is it okay if i write this code in performaction function after the console statement. And also is there any thing else we should write it in controller and do we have to create any route for that

Comment: Yes. It should work fine provided you insert the correct url and correct data.

Comment: function performaction(currentTime, duration) {
      console.log(currentTime);
      var data = {time: currentTime};
      var dataType = "json"
       $.post({   url: '/saveTime/'+videoId+'/'+userId,
        data: data,  
         success: function(data,status)
         {
            alert(status);
            alert(JSON.parse(data));
        },   dataType: dataType 
    });
    }

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a route `Route::post('/whatrouteyouwant/{video}/', 'videoController@saveTime')->name('video.saveTime');` and a controller method for it where you can actually get the user id and no need to pass it in the request.

Comment: i did this but i dont know what should we write in route for that and also in controller

Comment: In the controller you can get the data from `if($request->has('time')){$currentTime = $request->time;}` You should still validate the data before that using Laravel Validators

Comment: ok noe this is my route

Route::post('saveTime/{id}','InstructorCourseController@saveTime')->name('video.saveTime');

And  this is my method 

 public function saveTime(Request $request){

  
 }

But now i am not getting what data should i request from frontend.
If possible give the full method pleas.....

Comment: You should add your edits to your question as what you've tried.

Comment: I have updated the code above

Answer (score 1):

In your html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
```

In your javascript do this:

```
function performaction(currentTime, duration, videoId){//pass video id to this function where you call it.
    var data = {time: currentTime, duration: duration}; //data to send to server 
    var dataType = "json"//expected datatype from server 
    var headers = { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()}
    $.post({   
        url: '/saveTime/'+videoId,   //url of the server which stores time data   
        data: data,
        headers: headers,
        success: function(data,status){
                 alert(status);
                 var data = JSON.parse(data)
                 alert(data['message']);
        },   
        dataType: dataType 
    });
}
function resumePlayback(videoId){//Ajax request for getting the time
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getTime/'+videoId,
        success: function(data,status){
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(status == 200){
                document.getElementById('player').currentTime = data['playbackTime'];
                alert(playbackTime);
            }
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

In your `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::post('/saveTime/{video}', 'InstructorCourseController@saveTime')->name('video.saveTime');
Route::get('/getTime/{video}', 'InstructorCourseController@getTime')->name('video.getTime');//Route for getting the saved time
```

In your `InstructorCourseController.php`:

```
public function saveTime(Request $request, $video){
    $request->validate([
                'time' => 'required',
                'duration' => 'required'
        ]);
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user === null){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated', 403);
    }
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $video = Video::where('id',$video)->first();
    if($video === null){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Video not found', 404);
    }
    $currentTime = $request->time;
    $duration = $request->duration;
    //save them somewhere
    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Time saved', 200);//send http response as json back to the ajax call

}
public function getTime(Request $request, $video){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user === null){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated', 403);
    }
    $video = Video::where('id',$video)->first();
    //get the time from saved time where you saved it with this data
    $playbackTime = Somemodel::where('video_id',$video->id)->where('user_id',$user->id)->get()->last();//use this one if you insert the time instead of updating an existing row each time a time is saved.
    $playbackTime = Somemodel::where('video_id',$video->id)->where('user_id',$user->id)->first();//use this one if you update the time instead of inserting a new row each time a time is saved.

    if($playbackTime === null){
        //there's no saved time
        $playbackTime = 0;
    }else{
        $playbackTime = $playbackTime->currentTime;//use what column you saved the time in.
    }
    return response()->json(['playbackTime' => $playbackTime, 200);
}
```

Comment: Your code successfully worked. I don't know your name but i truly appreciate your help!
So one more last help i need is how to bring the user to saved time in video player?

Comment: @Abhishekpardeshi In javascript you can get the saved time from another route perhaps and set the video playback there?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try.

Comment: i tried using get method but still its not getting. So could you please give me the code for playing the video from saved time please.

Comment: Okay, I'll add the necessary code for it in the answer.

Comment: @Abhishekpardeshi Now I added the route, javascript and controller method for doing so.

Comment: @user3647971: it may be worth considering how much help to give a student. There is a point where a student asks for the bulk of their work to be done for them, and someone unfortunately complies with that request, that it would easily meet the academic definition of cheating.

Comment: @halfer I wouldn't know. I'm not a scholar myself. I just gave an example how it could be done in laravel not the exact code tho. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: I have a users table in which i have watch history column where i am storing an array as follows :
[{"lession_id":"156","progress":"4.618631"}]
And i am taking the video's from my lessions table.
I have added my method part in above controller methods.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for noticing but as i am student studying in India our exams has been cancelled and we are already promoted. So this is not for my academic project this is for my learning purpose.

Comment: @Abhishekpardeshi Well you can get that same data in the getTime function and return it as json response.

Comment: Still i didn't get it. Did u saw my output of time and lession_id [{"lession_id":"156","progress":"4.618631"}] And this is my watch_history column in users table

Comment: I have a users table in which watch_history column for each user and inside that i have an array which looks like 
[{"lession_id":"157","progress":"71.449464"},{"lession_id":"156","progress":"5.608"}]

And now i am not able to access the array because it looks like array inside array So please sir help me

Comment: @abhishekpardeshi You should update the question with what you currently have and more details.

Comment: @abhishekpardeshi Update your question. Not my answer.

Comment: yeah that only i have added i am not able to access the array value

Comment: The above code of storing time stores the time in array inside array so that's why i have updated the current code of storing time in database

Comment: if i check the getTime/{lession_id} route my output is :
{"playbackTime":"2.078864","0":200} which is correct but when i come to lession_video/{lession_id} route it's not playing the video from pause time..

Comment: @Abhishekpardeshi You should check the player documentation on how to adjust the current playbacktime. If it's a html <video> element then it's probably pretty straight forward, just set the time. For example `var video = document.getElementById('player'); video.currentTime = 0;//set the time of video`

Comment: @Abhishekpardeshi It is explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/av_prop_currenttime.asp)

Comment: I added in the answer for the javascript.

Comment: Hello sir. I want to show the top selling products by using the payments table in which i have user_id, course_id, amount. How the sql will be for this?